# MYSQL Query Automation on Weekly or Monthly Basis

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two table in database. Table1 gets data from some Utility program. I want to update my table2 by avg value on weekly or monthly basis without any user intervention.
Anyone having idea how to do that please guide me with example.
Thank You!!

Comment: Please use www.sqlfiddle.com to show your tables or paste your table structure and the query you tried with so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I want to update my table2 by avg value on weekly or monthly basis without any user intervention.*

You can automate using MySQL `event scheduler`.

You can define multiple schedulers for each of the event time, i.e. one for *weekly* updates and the other for *monthly* updates

**Example**:

```
delimiter //
drop event if exists monthly_event_scheduler_on_table2;

create event if not exists monthly_event_scheduler_on_table2
  on schedule every 1 month 
     -- you can change the following statement 
     -- to start it within next few minutes or so ...
     starts timestamp( current_date + interval 1 month, '00:00:00' )
     -- starts now();

  comment 'monthly update event scheduling on table2'
  do
    -- better practice is writing a procedure for the update process.
    call db_name.procedure_name_that_updates_the_table2_records();
;
//
delimiter ;
```

You can define a similar event that runs on every week on a scheduled timestamp.

Make sure that you do not have such event already defined. If exists, you have to drop it and create afresh with new definition.

**Refer to**: [*MySQL: CREATE EVENT Syntax*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

Default state of Event Scheduler is DISABLED.
You require to enable it by any of the following statements.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;
```

When the Event Scheduler is ON, the event scheduler thread is listed in the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as a daemon process, and its state is represented as shown here:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST\G
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 2
   User: event_scheduler
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Daemon
   Time: 3
  State: Waiting for next activation
   Info: NULL
```

Once the Event Scheduler is set ON, you would see it working.

**Refer to** : [MySQL Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)

Comment: I am trying to explore your suggested things.I will get back to you. Thanks a lot!!